# 403 Forbidden when attempting to list static files in Nginx docker container

Tags: docker, nginx

I created a small Nginx based container for hosting some static files so they can be downloaded later on via a HTTP client. I'm getting an odd error where if I try to access the container via localhost, it gives me a 403 Forbidden error. If I access the service via the hosts IP address or using 127.0.0.1, it works. Only when I connect using localhost as the hostname (E.g. `curl localhost:9999` does it fail. Below is the additional Nginx configuration that I created so list the static files. All other configuration is untouched and is in the same state as the normal Nginx Docker image.

```
server {
        autoindex on;
        location /{
           root /usr/share/nginx/html/;
        }
}
```

I've seen similar issues, but they seem to be more focused on file permission errors due to volumes, which I'm not using. All of the files are embedded in the image. Even then, because some file permissions were a bit restrictive before they were copied into the image, the last thing I do is run a chmod command to ensure all of the files are readable.

Edit:

Current error message:

```
2021/11/29 13:29:26 [error] 34#34: *1 directory index of "/usr/share/nginx/html/" is forbidden, client: 172.17.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost:9999"                                                    
172.17.0.1 - - [29/Nov/2021:13:29:26 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 403 153 "-" "curl/7.76.1" "-"
```

Comment: 127.0.0.1 does work and localhost does not work? That sounds like localhost is not pointing to 127.0.0.1. Also, you go to port 9999. Is the port mapped correctly? (Could you add the Dockerfile or docker-compose.yml also?

Comment: It does connect to the server, but I get a 403 Forbidden.  I'll update the question with the error I get.